# Cannot implicitly convert type 'ListName[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ListName>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I Have an IList that has certain properties. 
i access a set of values from database  to the code which returns IList. 
I have used a webservice which gives the complete details into the list. 
the service being WCF gets executed well in WCFTestClient.exe. 
However in codebehind it is showing an error when placed.

```
public IList<BrandInfo> SearchProduct(string name)
{
    AuthenicationServiceClient obj = new AuthenicationServiceClient();
    return obj.SearchProducts(name); 

}
```

it is showing an error "`Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model.BrandInfo[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Models.BrandInfo>'`"

the code in the webservice being.

```
public IList<BrandInfo> GetBrandByQuery(string query)
{
    List<BrandInfo> brands = Select.AllColumnsFrom<Brand>()
        .InnerJoin(Product.BrandIdColumn, Brand.BrandIdColumn)
        .InnerJoin(Category.CategoryIdColumn, Product.CategoryIdColumn)
        .InnerJoin(ProductPrice.ProductIdColumn, Product.ProductIdColumn)
        .Where(Product.EnabledColumn).IsEqualTo(true)
        .And(ProductPrice.PriceColumn).IsGreaterThan(0)
        .AndExpression(Product.Columns.Name).Like("%" + query + "%")
        .Or(Product.DescriptionColumn).Like("%" + query + "%")
        .Or(Category.CategoryNameColumn).Like("%" + query + "%")
        .OrderAsc(Brand.NameColumn.ColumnName)
        .Distinct()
        .ExecuteTypedList<BrandInfo>();

    // Feed other info here
    // ====================
    brands.ForEach(delegate(BrandInfo brand)
    {
        brand.Delivery = GetDelivery(brand.DeliveryId);
    });

    return brands;
}
```

How can i access this code from the client side. I couldn't extract any relevant online reference for this.

Comment: One way to fix this is to add `.ToArray()` at the end of your call - `obj.SearchProducts(name).ToArray();`  Since you appear to be using a Service Reference, you could alos set it to use `List<T>` when you add the reference, though I'd have to do it to tell you how.

Comment: tried all possibilities. but showing error @Tim

Comment: One thing I notice from your error message is that it clearly states:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model.BrandInfo[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Models.BrandInfo>'` See the difference between `Model.` and `Models.` Are the two related? Is there a namespace mismatch somehow? Are the two defined separately?

Comment: NB: The loop in `GetBrandByQuery` can be written more concisely as `foreach (BrandInfo brand in brands) { ... }`.

Comment: @nawfal yeah, both are residing in different projects, but having same structure for BrandInfo.

Comment: @Saurabh that wont help. For the compiler they are two different things. Why wouldn't you define it in one project? Or otherwise write a manual `Model.BrandInfo` to `Models.BrandInfo` conversion yourself and call it. Or use something like `AutoMapper` which does this automatically.

Answer (score 6):

One thing I notice from your error message is that it clearly states:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'Model.BrandInfo[]'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Models.BrandInfo>'`

`Model.BrandInfo` is different from `Models.BrandInfo` defined in separate projects. The compiler wouldn't make out the equivalence in such a manner. You have to either declare it in one project and reference it in the other, or you have to write a mapper yourself.

Something like

```
public IList<BrandInfo> SearchProduct(string name)
{
    AuthenicationServiceClient obj = new AuthenicationServiceClient();
    return obj.SearchProducts(name).Select(Convert).ToList(); 
}

public Models.BrandInfo Convert(Model.BrandInfo x)
{
    //your clone work here. 
}
```

Or you should try some libraries that automate this mapping like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: yes, am able to convert explicitly in the method Convert. Manually binding to the items required in the client side.

Answer (score 4):

You could do that using `ToList` method:

```
public IList<BrandInfo> SearchProduct(string name)
{
    AuthenicationServiceClient obj = new AuthenicationServiceClient();
    return obj.SearchProducts(name).ToList();
}
```

Remember, that it would require `using System.Linq` at the top of the file.

Or you can change your WCF configuration to deserialize collection as lists instead of arrays.

If you use *Add service reference* you should do following:

- Right click on the service reference and select *Configure Service Reference*.
- In the *Collection Type* drop-down, select correct type: something like `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: After adding ToList() to it, it is showing the following message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.BrandInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.BrandInfo>'" here BrandInfo class is copy pasted into the other project.